Are there different types of metric?
I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question. I'm reading Bernard Schutz's First Course In General Relativity (2nd edition) and in page 61 under the title 'Picture of a one-form', Schutz writes, "A vector itself does not automatically map
another vector into a real number. To do this it needs a metric tensor to define the scalar
product. With a different metric, the same two vectors will produce a different scalar product".
So what does Schutz mean by a different metric?

A metric d only need satisfy three requirements: $d(a,b)=d(b,a)$, $d(a,b)=0$ if and only if $a=b$ and also the triangle inequality: $d(a,b)\leq d(a,c)+d(c,b)$. But I think the author means a different inner-product space which is slightly different but not completely.

@RedFive The "metric" referred to here is, in fact, a metric tensor which is not the same thing as a metric from metric spaces. Yes, it's confusing. The tag [tag:metric-spaces] is not really appropriate here.

A healthy exercise: Equip the upper halfplane of $\mathbb R^2$ with the Euclidean metric $ds^2=dx^2+dy^2$ and alternatively with the Poincare metric $ds^2=\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{y^2},.$ What scalar curvatures do you get?

A 1-form is a linear map from the tangent space $T_x(\mathit M)$ to the number field, the coordinates of the tangent vector in a given base. Trivially, the linear maps form a linear space $T^*_x(\mathit M)$, too, by $$(l_1+l_2)(x)= l_1(x)+l_2(x)$$
The two spaces form a dual pair of spaces and a  canonical basis pair of the two spaces is normalized in such a way that the basis 1-forms $d_i$ project onto the $i$-component of a vector v:  $$E=\{e_k\},\quad  D=\{d_k\} : \quad  d_i\ \left(\sum_k v_k e_k\right)= v_i $$
The linear space machinery is working without any bilinear forms or metrics, including tensor products of linear maps and the construction of the product spaces of vectors as their argument sequences.
A bilinear symmetric form can be introduced as a symmetric tensor product of 1-forms
$$ g = \sum  g_{i,k}\  d_i\otimes_s d_k$$
such that
$$g(v,\_)=  \sum  g_{i,k}\  \left(d_i\otimes_s d_k\right)(v_,\_)=\frac{1}{2} \  \sum  g_{i,k}\  \left( d_i(v) d_k + d_k(v) \ d_i \right)=\frac{1}{2} \  \sum  g_{i,k}\  \left( v_i\  d_k + v_k \ d_i \right)$$
As a symmetric form, its matrix can be real diagonalized and scaled to a diagonal matrix with unit entries, yielding
$$g(v,\_) = \sum v_i  \ dx_i$$
If all diagonal elements have the same sign, g is a local euclidean metric (yielding a positive distance and a convergence principle).
Different signs define pseudo-Riemann manifolds. They demand a distinction between different subspaces of the local tangent bundle.
Eg in space-time the vector directions of timelike forward/backward, lightlike forward/backward and spacelike.
Any of these subspaces has its own euclidean metrics for the sake of defining differentiation and convergency of function series.
The signature of the metric tensor makes the fundamental difference between mathematical physics of waves in space-time and the 'nice' differential topology of euclidean manifolds, obscured by Einsteins genial algebraic extension of the Ricci calculus.
